# Создание многодокументного (MDI) интерфейса в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Рассмотрим, как это делается. Создаем простое приложение на Delphi. У появившейся главной формы приложения установите значение свойства FormStyle равным fsMDIForm. - ДА, СДЕЛАЛ.

Добавим в проект еще одну форму. (Кнопка New Form  панели инструментов) - НЕ ЗНАЮ ГДЕ НАЙТИ. Помогите найти. Желательно для Embarcadero X4.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте поближе ознакомиться с программным меню.

**File | New | Form – Delphi**